# Using a drag gesture inside a page tabview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a TabView and its tabviewstyle is of page. Now I need to know when the index changes and when the user have lifted their finger off the screen. I thought I would be able to use a drag gesture but I am having difficulty using this approach. This is how the code looks like:

```
    struct TestView: View {
        @State var currentIndex = 0
        
        var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                Color.red
                    .tag(0)

                Color.blue
                    .tag(1)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            .frame(height: 400)
            .onChange(of: currentIndex) { newValue in
                print("Current Index Changed")
            }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ x in
                       print("Gesture Changed")
                    })
                    .onEnded({ x in
                        print("Gesture Ended")
                    })
            )
        }
    }
```

Now on the drag gesture the onChanged is being called when u start dragging it but the onEnded is not getting called. The onEnded is only getting called when I drag up or down.  So how would I be able to do this using a drag gesture or what would be a different approach.

I tried adding a drag gesture and expect the onEnded to be called but it doesn't get called unless I drag up and down. I expected it to work when I drag right or left but it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

```
.simultaneousGesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20){
}
```

Comment: I would be helpful if you add where this code should go and why.